# Elasticsearch, find out searches where user didn't click any search result

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm trying to improve search quality.

The idea is basically,

> 1. SearchLog: when a user search something, log the query and search results (with a unique search id)
> 2. SearchClickLog: when a user clicks one of the search result, log the search id, position of the clicked item in the search result

I expect to find out searches which didn't result in a click

i.e How can I do something like select * from SearchLog where SearchClickLog doesn't exist in elasticsearch?

Am I thinking like sql-ish? 
Should I merge the two records into one document?
Should I use parent-child relationship in elasticsearch?

I'd like to seem them in kibana hopefully